# regex - allow only single digit numbers in a string

Tags: regex

I need to match a string that can be of length from 1 to 20 characters maximum, and it contains letters a-g and numbers 1-7. However, the numbers cannot be next to each other - only single digit numbers are allowed.

**Valid strings:** `aabbca1a6`, `4gg1g2g1`, `1`

**Invalid string:** `aabbca16a`  - theres two numbers next to each other, forming a two digit number 16.

I can match most strings quite easily with `[a-g1-7]{1,20}`, however i have no idea how to detect when two numbers are next to each other efficiently.

Currently in my program, after parsing through the regex, i'm just going through the whole string again in a loop, making sure there's no 2 numbers next to each other, however i'd prefer if  it all could be done with just one (simple) regex.

Comment: what is the language? if negative lookaheads are supported, then can use this one `^(?!.*\d{2}).*$`

Comment: I'm using it in a c++ program - `std::regex`.

Comment: ok, for std:regex it should work `^(?!.*\d{2})[a-g1-7]{1,20}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the answer from the comments by  [Ulugbek Umirov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803777/ulugbek-umirov) using negative lookahead at the start of an anchored string asserting not 2 digits to the right.

```
^(?!.*\d{2})[a-g1-7]{1,20}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\d{2})` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 digits
- `[a-g1-7]{1,20}` Repeat the ranges in the character class 1-20 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AwCru4/1)

Another option could be asserting the string length and repeat matching in a way that there can not be 2 digits next to each other

```
^(?=[a-g1-7]{1,20}$)[a-g]*(?:[1-7][a-g]+)*[0-7]?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1vOGTm/1)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest regex and approach is to check if it *doesn't* match:

```
.*\d\d.*
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to use this trick

-Check if number between 1-7 and character between a-g and the numbers are not siblings with each other by using this pattern

```
^[1-7]?([a-g]+[1-7]?)*
```

-Then you can check the length of string using string methods like (length method in JavaScript)